# res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", ...) is not setting the cookie in Node / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I have tried

```
  res.setHeader(
    "Set-Cookie",
    cookie.serialize("name", "name2", { path: "/", domain: "localhost" })
```

and

```
  res.setHeader(
    "Set-Cookie",
    cookie.serialize("name", "name2"))
```

and I have tried to set the cookie outright with

```
res.setHeader(
    "Set-Cookie",
    "name=name"})
```

but no cookie is set when I examine the res, and no cookie is received in my frontend. Everything is run locally. I do not understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. When using fetch() from the front end I didn't set the credentials flag to include. When I included the flag it worked instantly.

```
  return await fetch(
    `url`,
    { credentials: "include" }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make a cookie then try this instead of `res.setHeader()`:

```
res.cookie('cookieName', 'cookieValue');
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I can see the cookie field but no cookie is set in my front end. What I can understand the cookie header is for the front end to send back to the back end. Set cookie is sent from the back end in order to set a cookie, no?

Comment: Aha I see what you mean now, sorry that i misunderstood. 

That still does not work however... I can see that my set-cookie field is set in the backend when sending my response but there is no set-cookie field when looking in the browser...

Comment: This only works with Express